# Is there a more optimal way to apply these function to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to apply a function to two columns in a dataframe. 
The idea of the function is to split the value on each row of that column and then turn the split values into ints.

There are two types of values:

1. Dates as strings (e.g `"20.11.2020"`)
2. Lists of numbers as strings (e.g `"20,11,49,19,2"`)

The current way I achieve this is by doing:

```
def numerize_c(row):
    """
    Delim is colon
    """
    return [int(num) for num in row.split(",")]
    
def numerize_d(row):
    """
    Delim is dot
    """
    return [int(num) for num in row.split(".")]

data["corr_num"] = data["corr_num"].apply(numerize_c)
data["game_date"] = data["game_date"].apply(numerize_d)
```

I feel like this is a terribly inefficient way to do this. Is there a way, to for example give the functions an arg for the delimiters.

Or is there a way to format this into a lambda?

Comment: The column "corr_num" represents correct numbers from a board game this data is tracked for. 
Game date is ofc the date that we played that session.

I want to split these because I want to work on the values as integers.
Especially with corr_num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pd.DataFrame.apply`, `pd.Series.str.split` with regular expressions to split `'.'` or `','` all at once.

```
data.loc[:, ["corr_num", "game_date"]] =\
     data[["corr_num", "game_date"]].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(r',|\.'))
```

Comment: @matthew-hamilton also had a good answer, but I put this as best since it handles everything in one clean line and allows for more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement would be to use `data['corr_num'].str.split(',')`. This built-in is much faster than apply.